# Serial downvoter on security SE?

Tags: support, down-votes

Today I flagged several comments on my old deleted question. ~2h later I got downvotes for several old, downvoted questions. Is this some sort of serial downvoter?

[image: a]

Comment: I recently downvoted your "Honeypot for hunting browser zero-days" question.  When you first asked the question, I voted to close it, but didn't downvote it because it wasn't a bad question (just not on topic).  After your latest edits though (which attempted to answer it despite being closed and also aimed some insults at the people who closed it), I decided to downvote it.  All that to say, it doesn't surprise me that it got downvotes.  A serial downvoter is certainly not the only explanation for such things.

Answer (score 4):

If there is a serial downvoter, then the automatic systems in StackExchange will deal with it.

Comment: So, were the downvotes spread out over multiple days? Your screenshot shows a single day.

Comment: schroeder♦, I don't know, I detected it just today. Would be interesting to see if it continues in the next days. It least I started a topic and now can use it as reference if it continues.

Comment: @notyourdolly So, your idea is that someone is targetting you and downvoting a little each day (and that the votes are not legitimate)? That's a specific leap to make with, admittedly, no evidence, and evidence that could easily be explained through a non-malicious interpretation. Even if we could get evidence, there would be no way for us to determine if the voting was legitimate or not.

Comment: Only mods can see mod flags, so there is no correlation between your flags and the downvotes.